# Problema Toplevel en Boton

Tags: python, tkinter, botón

**Hola soy nuevo programando y estoy intentando poner abrir una ventana nueva con toplevel, apretando un boton, busque por todos lados y no pude. Porfavor si alguien puede ayudarme. Dejo el codigo. Lo unico que hace es abrir la ventana cuando ejecuto el programa .**

```
class botoneraframe2(Frame,):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master,width=500,height=200,bg="red")
        self.master=master
        self.pack()
        self.entrys()
        self.boton_eleccion()
        self.botones_enviar_borrar()
        

    def entrys(self):                
        self.entrypalabras=Entry(self,width=50,textvariable=barraescritura).place(x=0,y=20)   


    def boton_eleccion(self,):

        def topL():
            topLL=Toplevel()

            labelventana=Label(topLL)
            labelventana.pack()
            bt=Button(labelventana,text="BOTON")
            bt.pack()


self.BTONNUM=Button(self, text="Numeros",bg="lightgreen",height=2,command=topL()).place(x=300,y=60)
```

Comment: Recuerda que al poner parentesis al lado de una funcion, haces que se ejecute. Tenes que pasarle al boton la funcion en si misma, el objeto que la representa. Esto se logra pasandola sin poner los parentesis.

Comment: muchas gracias. me devolviste el alma al cuerpo. :D

Comment: De nada compa, me alegro de que tu alma haya vuelto a su lugar xD